# xgBoost, LambdaMart, hyperparam tuning, why is my score coming out as zero?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, xgboost, hyperparameters

I am building a LambdaMart learning to rank using xgboost but my NDSG scores keep coming out as zero and I don't have a clue why!

I have tried to use hyperparameter tuning to get the best model but my NDSG scores keep popping out as nan.

```
data_train = df
# Concatenate query ID and passage ID into a single column
data_train['query_passage_id'] = data_train['qid'].astype(str) + '_' + data['pid'].astype(str)

# Group passages by query-passage ID
data_grouped = data.groupby('query_passage_id').first().reset_index()


groups = data_grouped.groupby(['qid', 'pid']).size().values

# Compute the cumulative sum of the group sizes
group_cumsum = np.cumsum(groups)

# Add a zero to the beginning of the group_cumsum array
group_cumsum = np.concatenate(([0], group_cumsum))

groups_train = groups

X_val = df_val
# Concatenate query ID and passage ID into a single column
X_val['query_passage_id'] = X_val['qid'].astype(str) + '_' + X_val['pid'].astype(str)

y_val = df_val['relevancy']
X_val = X_val.drop(['query_passage_id', 'relevancy'], axis=1)

# Compute the group sizes for the validation data
groups_val = X_val.groupby('qid').size().values

# Compute the cumulative sum of the group sizes for the validation data
group_cumsum_val = np.cumsum(groups_val)
group_cumsum_val = np.concatenate(([0], group_cumsum_val))

# Split data into features and labels
X_train = data_grouped.drop(['query_passage_id', 'relevancy'], axis=1)
y_train = data_grouped['relevancy']



# Define the LambdaMART model with the rank:pairwise objective
model = xgb.XGBRanker(objective='rank:pairwise')


# Define the hyperparameter search space
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7]}

# Define the scoring metric for GridSearchCV
scoring = {'NDCG': make_scorer(ndcg_score, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=True)}

# Perform hyperparameter tuning with GridSearchCV
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring=scoring, refit='NDCG', verbose=3)
grid_search.fit(X, y, group=groups)


grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring=scoring, refit='NDCG', verbose=3)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train, group=groups_train, eval_set=[(X_val, y_val)], eval_group=[groups_val])




# Print the best hyperparameters and their score
print(f"Best hyperparameters: {grid_search.best_params_}")
print(f"Best score: {grid_search.best_score_}")
```

and my outputs are looking like:

```
[CV 2/5] END learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=7, n_estimators=150; NDCG: (test=nan) total time=   0.1s
[CV 3/5] END learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=7, n_estimators=150; NDCG: (test=nan) total time=   0.1s
[CV 4/5] END learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=7, n_estimators=150; NDCG: (test=nan) total time=   0.1s
[CV 5/5] END learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=7, n_estimators=150; NDCG: (test=nan) total time=   0.1s
Best hyperparameters: {'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_depth': 3, 'n_estimators': 50}
Best score: nan
```